# ASP.NET MVC 3 installed successfully but doesn't exist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows, iis-7

Win7: I opened the iis-->web installer

I installed ASP.net MVC 3.

I installed in the machine-node level
and in my specific website-node level

However, after installtion completes successfully,
It seems MVC 3 is still not installed.

I get the option "Add" again.

Tried restart but it didn't help.

Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "seems not installed"?

Comment: He says that, when he runs the installer again, it says "add" and not "modify" installation.  I suspect that's just the way this particular installer is configured.

Comment: @Elad: What were you expecting?  You won't get a program icon in the start menu; ASP.NET MVC is a programming framework, not an application.  See http://asp.net/mvc for some tutorials and "getting started" information.

Comment: Can you tell us whether the asp.net mvc 3 folder exists in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET ?